# Reject null value in two fields

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have the models:

```
class PotentialUser(models.Model):
    pass

class Lead(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'leads'

    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, null=True, unique=True)
    potential_user = models.ForeignKey(to=PotentialUser, null=True, unique=True)
```

And I want to allow `null` in the `user` field and in `potential_user` field, but not allow `null` to both fields together. How can I achieve it?

I have only one idea, in the models set `Meta.unique_together` and create one lead with `null` `user` and `null` `potential_user`. But is there a better way?

Comment: Use a custom validator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832390/django-sql-check

Comment: or use the form with your own clean method

Comment: I want add this validation in sql level, not in django forms, is there a that way?

Comment: @AndreyBerenda when you answer your own question you should post it as an answer not edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just added migrations like so:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('core', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql='ALTER TABLE leads ADD CONSTRAINT "leads_both_not_null" CHECK (user_id IS NOT NULL OR potential_user_id IS NOT NULL)',
            reverse_sql='ALTER TABLE core_example DROP CONSTRAINT "leads_both_not_null"'
        )
    ]
```